# Java - can't close Window because of infinite loop

Tags: java

When I'm starting game(snake game) through main menu, it does not work - it basicaly freezes and it is also probably because infinite loop that I've got there. But when I remove that loop, it does work as well as I can close app - I can't do it when game is launched from menu, but without that loop my snake can't move. And when I start game through main - just by calling class "View", it does work properly.

I know that I should probably use Threads instead of loop, but I have no idea how to use them properly.

Part of code that does not work:

```
public void Draw() throws InterruptedException, IOException{
        addKeyListener(this);
        bf = this.getBufferStrategy();



        while(true){
            tmp = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000; 
            sec = tmp - start;
            if (sec % 5 == 0) {
                Obstacles(30);
            }

            g = bf.getDrawGraphics();
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

            g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            for (int i = 0; i < obs.size(); i++) {
                g.fillRect(obs.get(i).x*SCALE, obs.get(i).y*SCALE, SCALE, SCALE);
            }


            for (Point point : snakeParts) {
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g.fillRect(point.x * SCALE, point.y * SCALE, SCALE, SCALE);
            }

            g.fillRect(head.x * SCALE, head.y * SCALE, SCALE, SCALE);   

            switch(kind){
                case 0:
                    g.setColor(Color.RED);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    break;
            }

            g.fillRect(bonus.x * SCALE, bonus.y * SCALE, SCALE, SCALE);

            string = "Score: " + score + ", Length: " + tailLength + ", Time: " + time / 20;
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);

            g.drawString(string, this.getWidth()/2-80, 45);

            Move();
            bf.show();
            Thread.sleep(speed);
        }
    }
```

And starting game from main-menu button:

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try 
        {
            if (cfg.nick())
            {
                this.setVisible(false);
                new View().setVisible(true);
                new View().startGame();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(HerniMenu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(HerniMenu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Scrap all of this -- just use a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). When you want to stop the Timer, simply call `stop()` on it, and it stops. It's so much easier than what you're doing, and it's thread-safe too (your code is most definitely not).

Comment: I suggest also looking into `SwingWorker`.

Comment: @LoganKulinski: that's over kill if all he's doing is a simple animation. A Swing Timer is much simpler and more idiot proof. I would use a SwingWorker if I had to run a long-running task, such as database access or file upload or download, but with an animation, the long-running part is the delay itself, which is what a Timer is built for.

Comment: You should use multithreading programming rather than just using a single thread..

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels you are correct, but I meant for them to research it for future GUI creation as well, if the situations you mentioned did ever come up.

Comment: ..........................@esea -- hello?

Answer (score 4):

This is a Swing program, and the easiest way to do repetitive tasks with Swing is via a Swing Timer. Please check the [Swing Timer Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for the details, but the gist of it is:

- You don't write code that loops -- your Timer would replace the for loop or while loop.
- Instead you create a `javax.swing.Timer` object by calling its constructor, passing in the delay time and an ActionListener.
- In that ActionListener's `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` method you write code that you want to have repeated.
- I'd advise against using threading directly for this unless you understand the [concurrency with Swing issues](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) (check the link). For instance if you do decide to use threading directly, either with the concurrency library, or Thread/Runnable, or SwingWorker, you would have to take care that any Swing calls made from within the background thread would have to be queued onto the Swing event thread, either via a SwingWorker's publish/process method pair or by passing a Runnable into a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` call. This is do-able, but it is more complicated than needed, and using a Swing Timer would be much simpler.
- To stop a Swing Timer, simply call the `stop()` method. Boom. That's it.
- Secondary issues: Swing graphics should be done in a passive way -- draw within the paintComponent method of a JPanel. What I would do would be to change the state of an `ArrayList<Point>` within my Swing Timer, call `repaint()` and then iterate through the ArrayList in my paintComponent method, drawing each snake segment at a location based on the Point positions in the ArrayList.

For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleSnake extends JPanel {

    private static final int PREF_W = 900;
    private static final int PREF_H = 650;
    private static final int SNAKE_WIDTH = 24;
    private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 20; // milliseconds  
    private static final int SNAKE_LENGTH = 20;
    private List<Point> pointList = new ArrayList<>();
    private boolean right = true;
    private boolean down = true;
    private JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
    private JButton stopButton = new JButton("Stop");
    private Timer swingTimer = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, e -> timerActionPerformed(e));

    public SimpleSnake() {
        // fill snake
        for (int i = 0; i < SNAKE_LENGTH; i++) {
            int x = (2 * (i + 1) * SNAKE_WIDTH) / 3;
            int y = (2 * (i + 1) * SNAKE_WIDTH) / 3;
            pointList.add(new Point(x, y));
        }

        startButton.addActionListener(e -> swingTimer.start());
        stopButton.addActionListener(e -> swingTimer.stop());

        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        add(startButton);
        add(stopButton);
    }

    // called by Swing Timer's ActionListener 
    private void timerActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        // get last point in ArrayList
        Point lastPoint = pointList.get(pointList.size() - 1);

        // if at any wall, reverse the direction of snake flow
        if (lastPoint.x - SNAKE_WIDTH / 2 < 0) {
            right = true;
        }
        if (lastPoint.x + SNAKE_WIDTH / 2 > getWidth()) {
            right = false;
        }
        if (lastPoint.y - SNAKE_WIDTH / 2 < 0) {
            down = true;
        }
        if (lastPoint.y + SNAKE_WIDTH / 2 > getHeight()) {
            down = false;
        }

        // remove first Point
        pointList.remove(0);

        // calculate the next Point to add
        int x = lastPoint.x;
        if (right) {
            x += (2 * SNAKE_WIDTH) / 3;
        } else {
            x -= (2 * SNAKE_WIDTH) / 3;            
        }

        int y = lastPoint.y;
        if (down) {
            y += (2 * SNAKE_WIDTH) / 3;
        } else {
            y -= (2 * SNAKE_WIDTH) / 3;            
        }

        // add point to ArrayList
        pointList.add(new Point(x, y));
        repaint();  // and repaint the JPanel
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // to make smooth graphics
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g; 
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        // iterate through the points, drawing the snake segments
        for (Point p : pointList) {
            int x = p.x - SNAKE_WIDTH / 2;
            int y = p.y - SNAKE_WIDTH / 2;
            g2.fillOval(x, y, SNAKE_WIDTH, SNAKE_WIDTH);
        }
    }

    // size the JPanel correctly
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleSnake");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new SimpleSnake());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you already diagnosed, the issue is that you have one thread doing all the logic to run your game and control the window. To fix this you will need to decouple the functionality into separate threads. There are numerous explanations and examples in the web, some of the basics are:
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/
- http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077138/java-concurrency/introduction-to-java-threads.html

Comment: This solution isn't wrong, but it adds increased complexity unnecessarily. Much better to use the tool in the Swing library built specifically for making repetitive calls.